# Get the attribute value with text() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Considering, I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="container" id="content-module">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
        <section class="app-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="m-b-xl col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                ...
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `h1` value ?

I tried :

```
$('#content-module > .wrap > .app-content > .row > .m-b-xl > h1').txt();
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is `txt()`? There is `text()`

Comment: wrap has no children... as the indentation implies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your jquery selector is caused by the fact the `div.wrap` element is closing without children yet you are selecting it as if it has children. To correctly use that chain of elements, you must remove the `.wrap` from the selection hierarchy and also correct the spelling of `.txt()` to `.text()`:

```
$('#content-module > .app-content > .row > .m-b-xl > h1').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can use:

```
$('h1').text();
```

In plain javascript, you can use:

```
var headingText = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent;
```

**Working Examples:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('jQuery returns: ' + $('h1').text());
  
});

var headingText = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent;
console.log('Plain javascript returns: ' + headingText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="content-module">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
        <section class="app-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="m-b-xl col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                ...
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```